# Use docker for different PHP versions in separate directories

Tags: php, docker, dedicated-server

I Dedicated Server on Godaddy.com which give me access to both WHM & cPanel let's say i created an account for domain **example.com** in this domain there is two directories **Attendance** which contain CodeIgniter required php 7.2 & **Prize** which contain Laravel required php 8.1. Can i use Docker to setup those directories properly and assign php version to each one ?

Comment: If you want to run two different versions of PHP at the same time, it's definitely easier to do so via Docker than to actually have two local versions installed on your server. And the configuration will be much simpler if you put them on their own separate third-level domains rather than subdirs of the same domain.

Comment: Is there a resource that explain this process in details ?